# adjust background with getwindow()

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard

I have looked at the following posts

- [How to keep background image size when software keyboard show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965857/how-to-keep-background-image-size-when-software-keyboard-show)
- [Software keyboard resizes background image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/android-soft-keyboard-resizes-background-image)
- [Overdraw and Romain Guy's blog post Android Performance Case Study](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906917/overdraw-and-romain-guys-blog-post-android-performance-case-study)

They all have similar problems and some have things they do to work around the problem, others are actually solved. As for my problem. I want to be able to scroll behind the keyboard while its visible without re-sizing my background image.

I am using this in my manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

It works but it re-sizes my background so I put this in my `onCreate` for my `fragment`.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.twoglobe_line);
```

Instead of setting the background in `XML` I set it in `Java`. This is the actual solution I needed. However it seems to be calling the parent `Activity's` window not the related `fragment's` window and my screen looks like this

```
Container 1    |     Container 2
               |
           <---Image--->
               |
               |
```

So the background image is half cut off. So my question is, how do I fix this? I will provide any code needed for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what your looking for is

```
this.getView().setBackgroundDrawable()
```

The getActivity() get the background for the entire activity, whereas the getView gets the view for only the fragment. Documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()
Try to never use getActivity() whenever possible. Even for findViewById, it is best to use getView(). For somethings like the context, there are no other options. Hope this works for you. Dont have a project setup to test it with, but I think it will work.

Comment: 3 for 3. You my friend are on fire