# OverDraw not consistent on all devices

Tags: android, performance

I was doing some Android Performance testing and notice that my app shows a nice see of blue on all activities when i turn on the "Show OverDraw" from the developer options.  Then i noticed that on one Nexus 5 running KitKat and another HTC ONE also running KitKat that everything was a sea of RED.  Why would there be overdraw on just kitKat devices?

Here is the xml for the layout in question (please pardon the hard coded dimensions and colors, i have talked to the team about that practice)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/light_layout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="Turn on light"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="Light"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_layout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.29"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/csZbarScannerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/rect_layout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/scanner_target_rect">

        </View>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/browse_tab"
            layout="@layout/footer_button"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/myitem_tab"
            layout="@layout/footer_button"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/checklist_tab"
            layout="@layout/footer_button"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/scan_tab"
            layout="@layout/footer_button"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></include>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is about programming in that it is a result of performance testing.. don't be a grump

Comment: OverDraw is a performance test to see the effects of a programmed app. It is a developer tool. It is used to insure the code one has written is not causing pixels to be drawn more than they need to, to insure the app performance is ideal.. you sir are just a grump.

Comment: Not all code is programming. Unless programming is not related with memory and performance profiling, monitoring, continuous integration, automated testing, business processes charts, application models, code design patterns, code style conventions, protocols, quality assurance, long etc. If you look around you, StackOverflow and other platforms are full of questions about these topics, and thank god it is like that. In fact I'm glad that you also answer questions that are not directly related to code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215587/android-xxhdpi-resources/19224838#19224838

Comment: erik, my bet is that it could be related to how the view hierarchy is drawn. Have you tried to explicitly nullify the background of the view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906917/overdraw-and-romain-guys-blog-post-android-performance-case-study
I'd also give a look to hierarchy viewer to see if there's any difference there.

Comment: I am going to add the xml for the view in question in an edit.  I can see no obvious reason for the overdraw issue.   I am thinking this is an OS version specific problem as it clean on icecream sandwhich and lollipop, just not kitkat